# How to save transparent background in Photoshop, for use in another program

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

How do I save a transparent background in Photoshop 7.0, for use in another program on a MAC, without losing the transparency?

Thanks,
psb

Comment: Hi paulasbartlion, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I think this question is pretty common among image novices. There was a time when I didn't know the answer either. :)

Comment: Does Photoshop 7 even run on OS X?

Comment: Bad news.. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2483937?start=0&tstart=0 I dont think mac os x supports PS 7.*

Answer (score 2):

Save it as a format which supports transparent background like PNG, GIF, TIFF, etc. (PNG is the best) DO NOT save it with JPG/JPEG, it doesn't support transparency.

To save it as PNG, select Save As from File Menu, a dialog box would appear, now select PNG (Portable Network Graphics) from the drop-menu and choose Save after giving it appropriate name.

Answer (score -1):

Saving the image as a TIFF (.tif) will give you the option to retain any layers within the original PSD file along with any paths and channels that you may have created too. Transparencies will be preserved.

The only downside is that the file size may be quite large.